# Safari push request permission returns "denied" in SAFARI 10.0.1

Tags: javascript, safari, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, macos-sierra

Trying to implement Safari pushes for my website i faced with a problem: after clicking a button the callback function returns permission equaled to "denied" without any pop-up window appearance.

Code below executes on controller that mapped for example.com/v1/log

```
file_put_contents ('./files/log.txt', json_encode ($_REQUEST));
```

and it writes '[]';

I tried my pushes in Safari 9 on El capitan OS, and it works fine for subscription and delivering, so i have no idea what a problem is for Safari 10 & Sierra OS.

Here is webpush.js code:

```
const websitePushID = 'web.com.example';
const webServiceUrl = 'https://example.com';
var permissionData = {};

window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    webPush.pushButton = $('.js-push-btn') || false;

    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
        navigator.serviceWorker.register('/service-worker.js').then(webPush.initialiseState);
        $('.js-push-btn').on('click', function () {
            webPush.do();
        });

    } else {
        if ('safari' in window && 'pushNotification' in window.safari) {
            permissionData = window.safari.pushNotification.permission(websitePushID);
            $('.js-push-btn').on('click', function () {
                checkRemotePermission(permissionData);
            });
        }
    }
});

var checkRemotePermission = function (permissionData) {
    if (permissionData.permission === 'default') {
        try {
            console.log('default');
            window.safari.pushNotification.requestPermission(
                webServiceUrl,
                websitePushID,
                {},
                checkRemotePermission
            );
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
    }
    else if (permissionData.permission === 'denied') {
        console.log('denied');
    }
    else if (permissionData.permission === 'granted') {
        console.log('granted');
    }
};
```

dat writes 'default' and after that 'denied' to the console log

Answer (score 0):

First of all check if you sign the signature file with apple's worldwide relation cerification authority.cer file which is mandatory from 14/2/16. Probably your are getting an error like unable to extract package. Usually if you are using any framework there is a permission error which does not allow to safari to send you the log files on your log's endpoint. That was my problem and when I solved these two thinks safari push all of its data like a charm! My advise first implement log endpoint then you will solve any error.